# LCD 18 (6 x3 ) Pinout without Datasheet AW -60i LCM V4.1

Tags: arduino, lcd, datasheet, pinout

I have this (18 X 3) LCD Pins, I need help to find the Datasheet or the pinout for it.

**AW -60i LCM V4.1**
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to find a way to take better photos. You need uniform illumination...the flash is ruining your photos.

Comment: Okey i'll take a new picture

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I changed the pictures.

Comment: Was this taken from existing equipment/electronics? If so, what?  (That might help identify the board.)